# Stripe form does not create any credit card

Tags: javascript, stripe-payments, forms

I'm a beginner with Stripe and i am struggling with the doc, i've tried several tutorials but none of them could make my form work.

The problem is that the form does create a token and a customer (i can see it in my Stripe Dashboard) but it does not create a credit card for that customer and when i try to subscribe that customer to a plan, i get an error.

here is my form's code:

```
<body>

    <div id="listblock">

        <div class="lines" id="logo">
            <h2>Pay from here! </h2>
        </div>

        <form action="payment.php" method="post" id="payment-form">
            <input class="card-number" type="text" required placeholder="1234 5678 8765 4321">
            <input class="card-expiry-month" type="number" required placeholder="MM">
            <input class="card-expiry-year" type="number" required placeholder="YY">
            <input class="card-cvc" type="number" required placeholder="CVC">
            <input type="radio" name="plan" value="1" checked>Basic annual subscription (99€/year)
            <input type="radio" name="plan" value="2" checked>Basic monthly subscription (9,99€/month)

            <button class="button" type="submit">Submit Payment</button>
        </form>

    </div>

</body>

<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v2/"></script>
<script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
    Stripe.setPublishableKey('my key is here');

    var $form = $('#payment-form'); // On récupère le formulaire

    $form.submit(function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();
        $form.find('button').prop('disabled', true); // On désactive le bouton submit

        Stripe.card.createToken({

            number:     $('.card-number').val(),
            cvc:        $('.card-cvc').val(),
            exp_month:  $('.card-expiry-month').val(),
            exp_year:   $('.card-expiry-year').val()

        }, function (status, response) {

            if (response.error) { // Ah une erreur !

                // On affiche les erreurs
                $form.find('.payment-errors').text(response.error.message);
                $form.find('button').prop('disabled', false); // On réactive le bouton

            } else { // Le token a bien été créé

                var token = response.id; // On récupère le token
                // On crée un champs cachée qui contiendra notre token
                $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken" />').val(token));
                $form.get(0).submit(); // On soumet le formulaire

            }
        });
    });


</script>
```

the error given by Stripe's API is:

```
    {
  "error": {
    "type": "invalid_request_error",
    "message": "This customer has no attached payment source"
  }
}
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Start by only using V2 or V3, not both.

Answer (score 1):

As it seems you are just developing your application, you should definitely use the updated version of Stripe which is v3.

Now, if you want your customer to subscribe in a recurrent payment plan, you should first create a **Subscription Plan** (Either using the API or from Dashboard), then create **Customer**. To create a customer you need to code like the following:

```
stripe.customers.create({
  email: "jenny.rosen@example.com",
}, function(err, customer) {
  // asynchronously called
});
```

And then subscribe the customer to the Plan you've already created. All of it is described in the [official doc](https://stripe.com/docs/subscriptions/quickstart) very nicely, just read it carefully.

Also, if you don't need to implement a recurrent subscription, just want to store the customer information for make later payment, you can just follow this [quick start guide](https://stripe.com/docs/quickstart), specifically [this part](https://stripe.com/docs/quickstart#saving-card-information).